# Problem looping through array filled with result of SQL query

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I currently have a PowerShell script which runs queries across 18 tables, generates text file output for each table, and merges these text files into an Excel file. I want to have this process run for each corp number I have via a loop.

I have this code right now:

```
$corplist = "select distinct bc01_corp from BC01" 

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString =
"Server=$SQLSERVER;Database=$DATABASE;Integrated Security=True;" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $corplist
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$cp = @($DataSet.Tables[0])

foreach ($bc01_corp in $cp)
{
write $bc01_corp 
write fml   
}

$Query1 = "SELECT * FROM BC01 where bc01_corp = $bc01_Corp"

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString =
"Server=$SQLSERVER;Database=$DATABASE;Integrated Security=True;" ##User ID = ; Password = ;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query1
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```

Everything runs up until the end of the for loop. The code prints the corp number and the string "fml" 22 times each; I have 22 distinct corp numbers in the bc01 table. However when I try to pass the bc01_corp value to query 1, I get the following error:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRow" could 
>   not be bound."
>   At C:\Users********\Documents\SQL Stuff for Sean - Codes\Parse out for each corp!.ps1:60 char:1
>   + $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

it looks like the variable being passed is "system.data.datarow) not the bc01_corp values, which is printed successfully to the console when I run the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you close your loop, and after it is done you try to reference `$bc01_corp` which only exists within the scope of your `ForEach` loop. You need to move your closing `}` for the loop to after the last line in your sample code (and probably after you do something with `$dataset` once it is filled). I would also create most of your objects outside the loop, and only update things inside it that need to be, most of which you've done in the initial connection and query.

```
foreach ($bc01_corp in $cp)
{
    write $bc01_corp 
    write fml   

    $Query1 = "SELECT * FROM BC01 where bc01_corp = $bc01_Corp"

    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query1
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

    <#
    Do stuff with $DataSet
    #>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i actually did have it all within the loop when i ran it. I still get that error. I will revise my question and add more info :D